# Average date diff on MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table named 'game_logs' with the following structure:

```
id: integer
user_id: integer
game_id: integer
game_event_type_id: integer
timestamp: datetime
```

I have to calculate the average time diff between events of type "3" (game_event_type_id=3) for records with the same user_id and game_id.

```
 id, user_id, game_id, game_event_type_id, timestamp
 '1', '45', '92', '3', '2014-06-02 15:36:04'
 '2', '45', '92', '3', '2014-06-02 15:36:17'
 '3', '45', '92', '3', '2014-06-02 15:36:25'
 '4', '20', '91', '3', '2014-06-02 15:37:15'
```

I have been trying different things but grouping by game_id and user_id and calculating the average at the same time seems challenging. I am left joining with the same table.

Can someone help me?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the average difference in seconds by doing:

```
select user_id, game_id,
       (case when count(*) > 1
             then timestampdiff(second, min(timestamp), max(timestamp)) / (count(*) - 1)
        end) as AvgDiffSeconds
from game_logs gl
where game_event_type_id = 3
group by user_id, game_id;
```

The key idea is that the average difference is the maximum minus the minimum divided by one less than the number of records.

Comment: Your idea makes a lot of sense. Although I get an error on the SQL sentence. I changed "end" for "end case" but still not working.

Answer (score -1):

You cannot do this with a single query.
Either use a stored procedure or do it on your application side (there it should be quite easy)